# Best way to store data in wpf app

Tags: wpf, mvvm, settings

I just want to know about the best way to store simple data in wfp application. I'm using SQL CE, but sometimes I need to store simple data (for instance one string). I don't want to use for it db, and I think it's the right decision.

Could you please give me a guidance on how should I do that in best way or any useful resource? 
Is there any particular features data settings storage for pattern MVVM?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Settings for exactly this scenario. It's simple, allows per user and system wide scenarios and is build into Visual Studio nicely.

Double clicking on Settings.settings in the Properties folder of your project (in Solution Explorer) brings up the editor and you can access these in code with something simple like `Properties.Settings.Default.StringPropertyX`.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to be upgrading in the future, I suggest that you create a small abstraction layer that you can upgrade to using any DB or other source, when you need to.
Until you do the upgrade, I would suggest a simple XML file using XDocument and XElement (and the rest of that api).
The reason why I am suggesting this is because you can use Linq on them easily and this enables you to change the provider in the future without any problems.

here is the MSDN on XDocument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx .

I hope this proves to be helpful to you ;-)

Cheers,

Max
p.s. lemme know if this is what you needed or not!

Answer (score 0):

If you publish the application through ClickOnce then you can use IsolatedStorage. It is pretty easy to use, just a few lines of code. You can learn how to use it on [WPF isolated storage](http://sourcecodedb.com/WPF-isolated-storage.html).

If you don't publish it through ClickOnce then I would suggest you keep it simple and use static class.

Answer (score -1):

you can use file system.. try to create xml file or csv file in the wpf app directory...

you can read and write to same file.. so that you can save what ever you want to that file and read from the same file..